# NiFi : reset the Filename sequence no./counter everyday

Tags: apache-nifi

Every 5 min i have a file generated from the NiFi Processor GenerateFlowFile:

filename_0.xml

filename_1.xml

filename_2.xml

....

I would like to asked how do i reset the sequence no. everyday ?

Thanks. Would appreciate help with example and explanation.

The first method i found is using nextInt():

[image]

[image]

the second method is using seq:

[image]

[image]

Please advise me with steps and example how can i automatically reset seq no./counter everyday. thanks

Comment: I'm still playing with this in my spare time (obviously I don't have much lol) but I think the general approach would be to store the current date (no time) using stateful UpdateAttribute after checking if it is different than the current date from using the `now()` EL function, in which case you statefully set some variable `base.counter` or something to nextInt(), then set the filename sequence number attribute to `${nextInt():minus(${base.counter}):minus(1)} or something like that. If I get a full solution I'll post it as an answer, this might get you closer in the meantime.